# How to read partitions from s3 data with multiple folder hierarchies using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried reading files with **multiple key=value in prefix as partitions**, though it works well with directories with fewer date partitions, it fails to list all the date partitions in my case (552 date partitions), and eventually times out.

Ex:
**
s3://bucketA/bronze/sc_reports/p_report_type=daily_transaction_reports/p_report_date=20200901/abc.parquet
s3://bucketA/bronze/sc_reports/p_report_type=daily_transaction_reports/p_report_date=20200902/xyz.parquet
**

The code I use :

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(appName).getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format(parquet).load(
            "s3://bucketA/bronze/sc_reports")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

df2 = spark.sql("select * from table1 where p_report_date=$date ")
```

```
enter code here
```

What's the optimal way to read multiple partitions with spark ?

Comment: is the current code taking long? you could try an iteration where you do the filter operations in pyspark API -- `df.filter(func.col('p_report_date') == date)`. I've seen this to be usually faster than spark-SQL queries.

Comment: This you find the answer?